# Export MS-Word drawings to TIFF and EPS

Tags: windows-7, macos, microsoft-word, tiff, eps

I have some drawings in my `docx` file. These drawing were accomplished by use of MS Word `2010 win` and `2011 mac` drawing features.
I am now required to export them separately in `TIFF` and `EPS` format.
I have both `OSX 10.9.5` and `Windows 7`.

> How can I do this?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just in case it is relevant, which version of Word?

Comment: The question is edited to address your comment . @Karan

Answer (score 1):

1. Group the drawings and copy it.
2. Open power point and past it in a blank layout.
3. Right click and select save as picture and select .tif and save.

If you want to save as EPS format you can follow these links and give it a try.

Note: I have not tested.

[MacPPT: How to Export PowerPoint Slides to EPS Format](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/188913/)

[Saving EPS files from Powerpoint](http://randomscribblepad.blogspot.com/2011/04/saving-eps-files-from-powerpoint.html)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution tested on Windows:

1. Save document as a web page.
2. Check the folder *Name_files* accompanying *Name.htm* and the drawings should be saved as PNG files.
3. Convert to whichever formats you want.

Comment: Well, That kills the quality and also it arises another question regarding to converting PNG to TIFF. As a matter of fact I can select the gropued drawing and copy it. Then in special paste I select meta file. this makes the drawing so good like a normal picture, but still I don't know how to export it as TIFF or EPS. @karan

Comment: Quality seems to be fine here; I'm not seeing a noticeable difference. PNG to TIFF/EPS can be accomplished by any number of free utilities with minimal loss. Direct export to TIFF/EPS might not be possible but I'll edit the answer if I find anything.